# EEA permit application

Tags: dependent-visa, europe

I live in Italy. I applied to visit the UK on an EEA family permit and was granted  6 months. I went to the UK twice and am back now in Italy, My permit is now expired.

Can I apply for another 6 months from Italy or do I have a time limit before I can apply for another 6 months? Like do I have to wait a year to apply for another 6 months?

Also, with a six month permit I know I would have to go with my wife who is Italian. While we are there, if she decide to stay in the UK for longer and I return to Italy by myself, would I be able to go back to the UK alone while the permit is valid (within the 6 months limit)? My wife would be in the UK already searching for a job.

Comment: What is your citizenship and what type of Italian residence permit do you have?

Comment: i have indefinite stay in italy and am from kenya

Answer (score 1):

The permit does not control how long you can stay in the UK.  Your right to be there flows automatically from your wife's nationality, your relationship to her, and European law.  You can stay in the UK indefinitely as long as your wife is there, although if your wife stays for longer than three months then she must be "qualified."

The permit just serves as a document to allow you to travel to and enter the UK, and as evidence that your documents have been reviewed and accepted by the Home Office.

> Can I apply for another 6 months from Italy

Yes.

> do I have a time limit before I can apply for another 6 months?

No.

> While we are there, if she decide to stay in the UK for longer and I return to Italy by myself, would I be able to go back to the UK alone while the permit is valid (within the 6 months limit)?

Yes.  You can enter the UK with a family permit if you are traveling with *or joining* your wife in the UK.